# Visual Studio project with a custom build step only (no default build)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to create a Visual Studio project that would allow me to see a bunch of JavaScript and other files and edit them as normal, but would also have a build step that can run any custom commands I want (currently some npm commands, possibly more later). Basically I want 3 features combined:

1. Be able to browse and edit files just like for any VS project (C#, C++, etc.)
2. Be able to run a custom build step by selecting "Build" in Visual Studio (including building the whole solution).
3. Be able to run that same custom build step from the command line (MSBuild).

Using a "shared project" (.shproj) allows me to easily see and edit the files, but there is no Build item in the context menu, even if I manually add a Build target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CodeSharing\Microsoft.CodeSharing.Common.Default.props" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CodeSharing\Microsoft.CodeSharing.Common.props" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CodeSharing\Microsoft.CodeSharing.CSharp.targets" />

  <Import Project="MyItems.projitems" Label="Shared" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="ECHO My custom build!" />
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

I've also tried using a stripped-down VC++ project (since I don't actually want to run the C++ compiler) and this allows a build to be run from VS, but opening the project logs warnings like `error MSB4057: The target "GetProjectDirectories" does not exist in the project.` and trying to add files to fails with that error or similar ones.

There must be an easier way to do this!

Comment: What did you want your project to be, a pure node.js console project or a js web project, a c# core compiler project? You should tell us the the type of other files. Build a project in VS IDE(the button) should clarify the type of project. Besides, if you want to build the whole project, you should clarify the type that the project will eventually generate. Using Build Button in VS IDE is not a simple thing.

Comment: And not sure how you modify the c++ vcxproj file that leads the error. Besides, button menu is from the `import targets="xxx\xxx.xxx"` system default files from the related project type folder of MSBuild folder on  the `xxx.proj` file. So you should make sure the type of your project that is going to generates finally. There are different import files for different types of projects. With them, you can use the Build Button in the VS IDE by using the imported VS build file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Perry Qian-MSFT's answer, I managed to strip down a Node.js project to the bare minimum that I needed to get Visual Studio to load and build it, but without referencing any external files.

The main trick was **VS needs a target named "CoreCompile" to be defined** to show the Build menu item! (It also needs a "Build" target, but that one is more obvious.)

My project now looks like this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>(some guid)</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectHome>.</ProjectHome>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AF33F2E-1136-4D97-BBB7-1795711AC8B8};{9092AA53-FB77-4645-B42D-1CCCA6BD08BD}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- These property groups can be empty, but need to be defined for VS -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="My.Build.targets" />
  
  <!-- Define empty standard MSBuild targets, since this project doesn't have them. Doing it this way allows My.Build.targets to also be used in a project that does define them. -->
  <Target Name="Build" />
  <Target Name="ReBuild" />
  <Target Name="Clean" />
  <!-- NOTE: a target named "CoreCompile" is needed for VS to display the Build menu item. -->
  <Target Name="CoreCompile" />

  <!-- Files shown in Visual Studio - adding and removing these in the UI works as expected -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="myfile..." />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And My.Build.targets looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="MyBuild" AfterTargets="Build">(build steps)</Target>
  <Target Name="MyReBuild" AfterTargets="ReBuild">(re-build steps)</Target>
  <Target Name="MyClean" AfterTargets="Clean">(clean steps)</Target>

  <!-- This target is needed just to suppress "warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project '...'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets
  required for restore." -->
  <Target Name="_IsProjectRestoreSupported" Returns="@(_ValidProjectsForRestore)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_ValidProjectsForRestore Include="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues. Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Do you know what MSBuild target I need to get VS2019 to *run* ("Start"/"Start without debugging") my custom project? Right now it gives this error: "Please select a startup file to launch by right-clicking the file in Solution Explorer and selecting 'Set as Node.js Startup File' or by modifying your configuration in project properties". I tried a target named "Run", but that doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

From your current description, I think you want to create a js project in VS IDE.

**However**, VS IDE has the [node js project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs?view=vs-2019) by default. And you should install the workload **Node.js development** under VS_Installer so that you can use it.

[image]

After that, you can create such project.

[image]

**1)** Adding js files or other files by right-click on the project-->**Add**-->**Existing Item** so that you can modify the files on VS IDE.

**2)** If you want to execute a custom build step that does not break the whole build, you should make the custom target depends on the default build.

You can use this:

```
<Target Name="CustomStep" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="ECHO My custom build!" />
</Target>
```

or

```
<Target Name="CustomStep" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="ECHO My custom build!" />
</Target>
```

**Note**: If you use

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="ECHO My custom build!" />
  </Target>
```

It will overwrite the system build process and instead, run the command, which breaks the whole default build.

**3)** If you want to execute the custom build on msbuild command, you should specify the name of the custom target:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.proj -t: CustomStep(the name of the custom target)
```

===============================================

**Besides**, if you still want to use **C++** project template, you could create a empty c++ project which does not contain any clcompile files and then do the same steps.

[image]

If you do not want to use **C++ compiler**, you should only remove any xml node on the `vcxproj` file like these:

```
 <ClCompile Include="xxx.cpp" />
 <ClInclude Include="xxx.h" />
```

**When** you use the empty C++ project, you do not have to worry about that.

=========================================

**Update 1**

If you want to build this project on a build sever without VS IDE, I suggest you could install `Build Tool for VS2019` which is an independent, lightweight build command line(It is equivalent to `dotnet cli`).

[Build Tool for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

Under **All Downloads**-->**Tools for Visual Studio 2019**--> **Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019**

**Then**, you have to install the related build workload such as **Node.js Build tools** and then we can use the command line to build node.js project on build sever.

The entire installation process is fast.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a Node.js project worked reasonably well (even though my project is not a Node.js project). I was able to add a custom build step.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And I think my answer does help. If my answer helps you handle and understand the issue better, please do not forget to accept it. And if you have any other concern, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: Thank you, I do have other concerns: I need this project to also be buildable from the command line (ideally by running `dotnet build`, but an msbuild command would also do) on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed.

Using a Node.js project for this is still a workaround, rather than exactly what I was looking for: a project that is *just* a collection of files that can be edited in VS and built using my custom build step in VS and from the command line.

Comment: `dotnet build` is for building new-sdk projects(net core and net standard).Unless you create a new template `net core` project, add your content files directly to the project, and then write your custom build steps according to my steps 2, 3, because you use the default net core project, as long as you don’t Move any file about xxx.cs, then there will be no problems. So you can use `dotnet build` with that.

Comment: However, vs has an independent, lightweight build tool which is equivalent to `dotnet cli`. You have to download the build tool for VS2019. See my update answer. It is like an independent command line which can build node js projects with the related build workload. Then, use `msbuild xxx.xxx.njsproj -t:build`. So you do not have to worry about that. There are many solutions to meet your requirements:)

Comment: I want to be able to build it on Linux as well, using the MSBuild that comes with .NET Core SDK.

Comment: If you still want to use `dotnet cli`, and insist on using this on linux, `build tool for vs` might not work. You only have to create a `net core` console project, and then try my following steps to add the content into this project. Add suctom build step which you executes your own build process.

Comment: Linux only supports cross-platform sdk. Net Core sdk, so you have to use the `net core` project.

Comment: If I create a .NET Core project building it creates a .dll in the bin directory, even if I have no .cs files and even if I override the "Build" target. I don't want that. I want it to run *only* my build.

Comment: I managed to remove almost everything from the Node.js project, so that it builds without VS or even VS Build tools. Posted it as an answer. Thanks for your help! (I do wish MS would make this easier, though.)