# Custom MSBuild project that can be "run" from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I created a custom MSBuild project that I can "build" from Visual Studio 2019, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917535/1536933. That is, I can select the Build menu item in VS and it runs my custom MSBuild task. Is there a way to do the same with "Run" - get VS to run my custom MSBuild task when I "Start" (or "Start without debugging") that project? I worked out that for the Build menu item to appear VS needs to see MSBuild targets named "Build" and "CoreCompile" - there is probably some equivalent for Start, but what?

The custom project file looks like this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>(some guid)</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectHome>.</ProjectHome>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AF33F2E-1136-4D97-BBB7-1795711AC8B8};{9092AA53-FB77-4645-B42D-1CCCA6BD08BD}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- These property groups can be empty, but need to be defined for VS -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="My.Build.targets" />
  
  <!-- Define empty standard MSBuild targets, since this project doesn't have them. Doing it this way allows My.Build.targets to also be used in a project that does define them. -->
  <Target Name="Build" />
  <Target Name="ReBuild" />
  <Target Name="Clean" />
  <!-- NOTE: a target named "CoreCompile" is needed for VS to display the Build menu item. -->
  <Target Name="CoreCompile" />

  <!-- Files shown in Visual Studio - adding and removing these in the UI works as expected -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="myfile..." />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that it's not a C# project or C++ project or any other common type of project - VS treats its as a Node.js project due to the ProjectTypeGuids, but if I can get it working some other way, I'd be happy to.

Comment: It depends on the files which you want to, c++ or c# or any other files. When you debug, you should not forget to add the related compile files and then add the entry main function to let the debugger know the entrance. Also, please do not forget to add the related `DefineConstants` msbuild property under proj file.

Comment: There are no c++ nor c# files and I don't want to *debug* anything, only to *run* a custom MSBuild action whenever the user runs the project in VS (Debug, Start without debugging or Debug, Start debugging - I'd like those to do the same thing, but even if only "Start without debugging" worked that would be something!)

Comment: What is `DefineConstants` for in this case @SaraLiu-MSFT?

Comment: ohh. that is for c# compiler parameter. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019#list-of-common-properties-and-parameters). That might a bit different. If you want to debug, you should generate the final executable program, so that it could debug,